# WooCommerce: Display Custom Fields in Email Invoice to Store Owner

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to get various custom fields that I created via functions.php to appear in the emails that get sent to the client / store owner so she can see the results. Unfortunately, this code I also added to functions.php isn't appearing in those emails. Here's what I'm using:

```
/**
* Add a custom field (in an order) to the emails
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );

function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['meta_key'] = array(
        'label1' => __( 'Child&#39;s Name' ),
        'value1' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_aba_childs_name', true ),
        'label2' => __( 'Child&#39;s Age' ),
        'value2' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_aba_age', true ),
        'label3' => __( 'Grade' ),
        'value3' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_aba_grade', true ),
        'label4' => __( 'Is this a Gift&#63;' ),
        'value4' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_aba_gift', true ),
        'label5' => __( 'How did You Hear About Us&#63;' ),
        'value5' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_aba_hear', true ),
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

So there's five custom fields I need to display and it's just not working for me. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an associative array for each custom field. Not a single one.

[Here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-emails.html#source-view.488) is the documentation of the **`woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields`** hook.

Furthermore, the order id must be retrieved via the `$order->get_id()` method and not directly accessing the `$order->id` property. Otherwise a PHP Notice will be generated:

> PHP Notice: id was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed
> directly.

So, to work, you need to modify your function with the following:

```
/*
 * Add a custom field (in an order) to the emails
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    // adds the "_aba_childs_name" field
    $fields['_aba_childs_name'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Child&#39;s Name' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_aba_childs_name', true )
    );
    // adds the "_aba_age" field
    $fields['_aba_age'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Child&#39;s Age' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_aba_age', true )
    );
    // adds the "_aba_grade" field
    $fields['_aba_grade'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Grade' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_aba_grade', true )
    );
    // adds the "_aba_gift" field
    $fields['_aba_gift'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Is this a Gift&#63;' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_aba_gift', true )
    );
    // adds the "_aba_hear" field
    $fields['_aba_hear'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'How did You Hear About Us&#63;' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_aba_hear', true )
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it in the functions.php of your active theme.*

Comment: Thanks for explaining that and providing the solution. Appreciate it.